# Spring integration - Retry to establish connection on exception scenarios

Tags: spring, spring-integration

My application communicates to a third party system using spring integration. I send a payload for which I get a response that I parse and use. All good. Please find below the SI xml that I use.

Now I want to application retry to establish connection on exception scenarios where the server I'm trying to connect isn't available or on time outs or if it refuses to connect etc. 
How can I achieve this using SI xml configuration? Please guide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">



<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface=" com.RxGateway"
    default-request-channel="objectOut" />

<int:channel id="objectOut" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="10.236.249.xx" port="9103" single-use="false"
    so-timeout="50000000" using-nio="false" so-keep-alive="true"
    serializer="customDSerializer" deserializer="customDSerializer" />

<bean id="customDSerializer" class="com.CustomSerializerDeserializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="4096" />
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="objectOut" reply-channel="toSA" connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="100000" reply-timeout="50000"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
    ref="rxService" method="parseResponse"/>

<bean id="rxService" class="com.RxService"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" />
<int:channel id="bytesIn" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `retry-advice` into your `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway>`:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway>
    <int-ip:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice/>
    </int-ip:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway>
```

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: That's correct, you can do that with retry support in the Framework.

Comment: Thanks, Artem! I would want to retry for 3 times with a gap of 5 seconds. After roughly going through docs, I think I should be able to do something like below,                                                                
    `<int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <int:retry-advice id="retrier" max-attempts="4" recovery-channel="myErrorChannel">
    <int:fixed-back-off initial="5000"  maximum="60000" />
    </int:retry-advice>
    </request-handler-advice-chain>`

Comment: I'll be trying this tomorrow. Meanwhile, could you tell me if I'm expected to define recovery-channel="myErrorChannel"? I don't want any exceptions thrown, but should be able to continue with the rest of my code if I'm not able to connect to the server. Is there any specific I should be doing for that?

Comment: Right. If you want to swallow exceptions, you need to have that `recovery-channel`

Comment: Thanks, Artem. Will try this out and come back if I have any questions. Many thanks!